# Nginx negative rewrite location rules

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

URLs:

```
1) /store/doc/some_file.doc
2) /store/doc/some_dir/some_file.doc
3) /store/img/some_file.doc
4) /store/img/some_dir/some_file.doc
5) /store/xxx/some_file.doc
6) /store/xxx/some_dir/some_file.doc
```

Nginx conf:

```
location /storage/ {
   location ^~/storage/[^(doc|img)]/(.*) {
       return 418;
   }
   rewrite ^/storage/(doc|img)/(.*) /storage/_storage.php?type=$1&file=$2 break;
}
```

What i want to do:

1. all URLs what started by `/storage/` need specific processing
2. if URL doesn't match with `/storage/doc/*` or `/storage/img/*` - return "I'm reapod" code
3. if URL match with `/storage/doc/*` or `/storage/img/*` - send this request to special file for processing (`/storage/_storage.php`) with additional GET-param in URL (first param - type [doc or img], second param - URL part after `/storage/doc/` or `/storage/img/`)

For 1-4 URLs all work fine, but  for 5 and 6 URLs doesn't send 418.

I don't understand how to write negative location condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
location /storage/ {
   location ~/storage/[^(doc|img)] { # <--- All what not start by doc or img will be passed
       return 418;
   }
   rewrite ^/storage/(doc|img)/(.*) /storage/_storage.php?type=$1&file=$2 break;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).